# Help with Processing code run exception, incorrect classpath

Tags: java, processing

I'm running processing on linux with the jvm bundle. When I type in tutorial code and run it I get the following error:

incorrect classpath: /usr/java/jdk2.6.0_06/lib

can you modify processing's java classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your CLASSPATH environment variable is screwed up. Not sure how, but the path should almost certainly not have the `2` in it.

Try changing your CLASSPATH enviroment variable. First verify that it's wrong though.

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

It should be jdk1.6.0_06 not jdk2.6.0_06. Also, you really should update your JDK version. There have been significant changes since then.